# Bootstrap 3 Tabs, active tab flicker on hover only in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Firstly here's the [link](http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/firefox-issue.html)

I've setup bootstrap3 tabs for some content. Only in firefox I get a flickr when I click the active tab and hover out.

Chrome Link(works without issues): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2gMde9M2-A&feature=youtu.be

Firefox Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnpuUHTBxJo&feature=youtu.be

I did try to solve it myself but could not find any related styles which may be causing this. Maybe I've missed something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a:focus, a:active { 
    outline: none; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you need remove this css

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #DDDDDD #DDDDDD rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #555555;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Manjunath. Had to overwrite the styles.